# Angular chart: can't send the data to the chart

Tags: angularjs, charts

I'm trying to build a chart with angular
my problem is to send the data received by the API to the chart
The json i receive is like this:
{"2016":"8441,7728,10600,7297,8939,8622,5142,4718,8782,7325,7325,5222","2017":"7491,6245,7723,4701,6439,6111,7496,3724,7502,2839"}
i do:

```
    $http({  
          method: 'POST',  
          data    : {famille: selectedFamille.Id, societe: $scope.societe},  
          url: '/api/EBP/get_the_ca.php',  
          dataType : "json",  
    }).then(function (response) {  
        // on success, we send the information to the chart         
        $scope.labels = ["Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juilley", "Août", "Sept.", "Oct.", "Nov.", "Déc."];  
        $scope.series = ['CA 2016', 'CA 2017'];  

        $scope.datasetOverride = [{  
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'  
        }, {  
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-2'  
        }];  

        $scope.options = {   
            legend: {  
                display: true  
            },            
             scales: {  
                yAxes: [{  
                    id: 'y-axis-1',  
                    type: 'linear',  
                    display: true,  
                    position: 'left',  
                    ticks: {min: 0, max:100000}  
                }]  
            }  
        };

        $scope.data = [  
            [response.data['2016']],  
            [response.data['2017']]  
        ];
```

everything works fine if between response.data['2016'] and response.data['2017'] i put the content of those vars

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: the chart display nothing, if i put the content in place of response.data['2016'] and response.data['2017'] it works.

Comment: you probably need to manipulate the data to create a different structure, the syntax you have there won't work with your current data format.

Comment: yes you are right, the format is not accept.